# Can someone walk me through the derivative of $x\mapsto 4\arcsin\left(x^3\right)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$ 4\arcsin(x^3) $$

The whole differentiation process for inverse functions has slipped me.

Comment: Why don't you ask help for finding the derivative of the more fundamental (an simple) $\arcsin x$?

Comment: Do you need a formula for the derivative of the arcsine?  Or is your question more about how the chain rule works in this particular case?

Comment: hint: with $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$ you will get $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Just watched a Khan Academy video on arcsinx. Still need help with the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, 
$$
(f^{-1})'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}
$$
Let's apply that to arcsine:

$$
\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sin'(\arcsin(x))} 
\\
=  \frac{1}{\cos(\arcsin(x))} 
$$

So then the question is "what's the cosine of an angle whose sine is $x$?" Draw a triangle with vertical leg x and horizontal leg $\sqrt{1 - x^2}$, and hypotenuse $1$. (Check that this satisfies Pythagoras!). The sine of this angle is $x$, so its cosine is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So

$$
\arcsin'(x) = \frac{1}{\sin'(\arcsin(x))} 
\\
=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}. 
$$

Now you want the derivative of $4\arcsin(x^3)$, so you need to apply the chain rule:

$$
(4\arcsin(x^3))' = 4\arcsin'(x^3) \cdot (3 x^2)\\
= 4\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x^3)^2}} 3 x^2 \\
= \frac{12x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^6}}.
$$

Comment: It's $\arcsin(x^3)$.

Comment: Thanks...I've fixed it. (That noise you heard was me slapping my forehead...)

Comment: Fixed. Another forehead-slap. Someday I'm gonna learn how to read as well as how to do calculus problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $y=4\arcsin x^3$ then $x^3=\sin \frac y4$

Differentiate this with respect to $x$ using the chain rule to obtain $$3x^2=\frac {y'}4\cos \frac y4$$

Now $\cos \frac y4=\sqrt {1-\sin^2 \frac y4}=\sqrt {1-x^6}$ so that $$y'=\frac {12x^2}{\sqrt {1-x^6}}$$

---

This implicit differentiation is a method you can use if you forget the formula and don't have tables.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=4\arcsin(x^3).$
We want $y'$.

Now, $\sin(y/4)=x^3$. Differentiating both sides wrt $x$ we get: $\frac{1}{4}\cos(y/4).y'=3x^2$.

Now, express $\cos(y/4)$ in terms of $x$ from the relation $\sin(y/4)=x^3$